How to make wiremock to record the whole request (the query params, request body/headers etc) rather than just the hash of request?
How to make wiremock to record the whole request (the query params, request body/headers etc) rather than just the hash of request?
I need to achieve this programmatically. This is how my recording spec looks at the moment.
var spec = new RecordSpec(
    null,
    null,
    headers,
    (r -> new RegexPattern(".*")),
    null,
    SnapshotOutputFormatter.FULL,
    false,
    true,
    null,
    null
);

May be I am missing something but otherwise, I don't find any option here to include the whole request in the recording. I am not so expert in wiremock.  May be RecordSpec  supports it but I am not sure how to configure it to record the whole request.
wiremock i am using is org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-wiremock:4.0.4
The problem I want to solve is: debug Request was not matched issue.

x-abc-body-hash: 1838658540                                |
x-abc-body-hash: 1882620460                         <<<<< Header does
not match

If I can see the request body(not just he hash) as in the recoding and as in the playback, I will be able to solve my issue.

just changed (r -> new RegexPattern(".*")) to null and it recorded the whole request body.
var spec = new RecordSpec(
    null,
    null,
    headers,
    null,
    null,
    SnapshotOutputFormatter.FULL,
    false,
    true,
    null,
    null
);

